# Shadow changes after reopening Illustrator file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shadows, drop-shadow

ok, this is really weird. I downloaded an illustration (as an AI file) from Freepik. When I copy-paste this to my file, all the shadows you see here look good:

[image]

Then I saved the file and closed it. When i reopened the file, suddenly the shadows look like this:

[image]

It looks like the gradients have changed angles or something... I don't know. I haven't touched anything, all I did was save the file. I tried the same thing with new file, same thing happens. But the original Freepik file is just fine after saving and re-opening.

Can anyone tell me what could cause this kind of issue? Thanks.

Comment: I actually started my post with saying "Hi" but it's not displaying and editing the post doesn't help. Sorry about that. :)

Comment: I looked into the original file. If, for example, I change the desktop screen's color, save, close and re-open the file, same thing happens. The shadwos look horrible. I don't understand what causes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t think of a reason for this issue other than some sort of legacy art thing.

I know this is not your question, but a quick fix might be to select all the gradients and reverse their direction:

[image]